# Javascript (or pseudocode) to properly append two PNGs using arraybuffers/canvas

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, png

I have two images (when combined will have a 1:1 width:height ratio). If I combine them using `convert a.png b.png -append c.png` on unix, it works perfectly. I'm trying to achieve this in javascript. I'm adding the arraybuffers (containing img data) together because drawing them both in a canvas doesn't seem to produce the identical image. If I simply append each arraybuffer, the image ration is 2:1; does anyone know how to properly append the array buffers, similar to what `convert` does?

Edit: To elaborate, simply stacking on a canvas *won't* work (I've tried). This could be due to low level canvas code, I suspect it's due to how canvas joins the pixels at the boundary between the two images. It needs to be arraybuffers.

Comment: How do you fill the arraybuffer/XHR?

Comment: I have loaded them from ajax get requests: the data is correct and present, but simply appending two buffers creates the vertical merge: I need horizontal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you for some reason don't want to load the images via `Image` then the only option is to manually parse and decompress the file. It's true that the browser can alter images due to ICC/gamma support. This doesn't happen in the canvas step though, but during image loading and converting to RGBA data.

That being said, the process during `getImageDate()`/`putImageData()` can also alter the pixel values due to (un-)pre-multiplying and rounding errors.

Example using canvas to merge two PNG images into a single one:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),                   // canvas 2d context
    img1 = new Image,                           // create two image
    img2 = new Image,                           // elements
    count = 2;                                  // Track for loader

// load images
img1.onload = img2.onload = function() {        // make sure images are
  if (!--count) append();                       // loaded first
};
img1.crossOrigin = img2.crossOrigin = "";       // need this for this demo
img1.src = "http://i.imgur.com/hlHEhUhb.jpg";   // random images...
img2.src = "http://i.imgur.com/ynzkv40b.jpg";

// process images
function append() {

  // use width to sum the images
  c.width = img1.width + img2.width;            // set total height 
  c.height = Math.max(img1.height,img2.height); // set max height
  
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);                    // draw in image 1
  ctx.drawImage(img2, img1.width, 0) ;          // draw in image 2
  
  console.log(c.toDataURL());                   // extract, send to server
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

You cannot simply merge PNG data with each other without decoding them first. This is because the image data chunk is compressed (deflated) and each scan-line in a PNG file is using a initial byte describing the line-filter being used.

Simply merging them could possibly invalidate the deflated data if just vertical, and horizontally it would invalidate the line data vs. length due to the extra filter byte that would be introduced. The filters for each line could be different as well.

So there is no way around parsing, decompressing and decoding the source PNG files. But in order to parse a PNG file you would have to know how the file format is built up.

### The PNG file format

The main file structure in a PNG files is:

```
-Signature-     8 bytes
IHDR chunk      required (width, height, depth, mode etc.)
[PLTE chunk]    required for indexed color mode
[Misc chunks]   optional ancillary and private chunks
IDAT chunk      required, can be multiple
IEND chunk      required, last chunk (data-less)
```

Any other chunk can be ignored in this case unless you are using an indexed palette in which case you need to consider the PLTE chunk as well.

Chunks allow you to skip to next chunk if the current chunk is unknown or not needed. A chunk is structured using 8 bytes, followed by data and then a 4 bytes CRC-32 checksum (data is not required, like with the IEND chunk):

```
0x00 SIZE     (4 bytes)
0x04 FOURCC   (4 bytes)
0x08 DATA     (variable, can be 0)
0x?? CRC-32   (4 bytes)
```

The size is representing the data only. The name would be a ASCII representation of the chunk name, always four bytes ("IDAT", "IEND", ...).

The CRC-32 checksum can be ignored if you don't wish to validate the data, but cannot be ignored when you produce a new PNG file as most PNG viewers/parser uses this value and it includes the chunk name.

All values are unsigned in big-endian byte order.

### Reading Chunks

A typical way to read chunked data files such as PNG is to initialize a start offset at the first chunk. Then iterate through reading and moving the file cursor at the same time, checking the chunk name.

**For example:**

```
var pos = 8;                          // first chunk position
var dv = new DataView(arraybuffer);   // use a DataView
```

Make some helper functions to read and move position:

```
function getUint32() {                // and for Uint16 etc.
  var data = dv.getUint32(pos);       // use big-endian byte-order
  pos += 4;
  return data
}

// decode chunk name to string (from pngtoy)
function getFourCC() {
    var v = getUint32(),
        c = String.fromCharCode;
    return  c((v & 0xff000000)>>>24) + c((v & 0xff0000)>>>16) + 
            c((v & 0xff00)>>>8) + c((v & 0xff)>>>0)
}
```

Which now allows us to work with the file buffer as intended:

```
// repeated actions:
var size = getUint32();
var name = getFourCC();
var data, crc;

if (name === "IHDR") {                          // check chunk type
  data = new Uint8Array(dv.buffer, pos, size);  // get data section from chunk
  pos += size;                                  // next chunk or the end
  crc = getUint32();                            // read CRC-32 checksum
  // validate CRC-32 here
}
else pos += size + 4;                           // skip data and crc
```

Tip: even if the chunk is skipped it could be a point validating the data against the CRC checksum to find early indication of file corruption.

The IDAT chunk *always* contains deflated data since this is the only valid storage form in the format specification, and has to be inflated first. For this process I would recommend (as always) the [Pako implementation of the zlib library](https://github.com/nodeca/pako).

### Reading process

The read process for each input image then becomes (using a `DataView` is required):

- Check magic header/signature. There are 8 bytes which should always be the sequence of:
  `0x89504E47 0x0D0A1A0A` (big-endian).
- If OK the first chunk (IHDR) would be found at position 8 in the file. You need to parse the content of this header to find width, height as well as bitmap depth (16, 8, 4, 1) and type (RGB, RGBA, Greyscale, Bitmap etc.) as well as if the image is interlaced or not.
- When these data has been obtained you can scan the IDAT chunks. Note the plural - there is usually just a single IDAT chunk but it is perfectly valid to have several IDAT chunks. When you reach the IEND chunk there is no more data. A valid PNG file will not have any other chunks between the IDAT and IEND chunks when the bitmap is split into several IDAT chunks.
- Pass the data through inflate to decompress it. (tip: using Inflate the instance instead of the static function can take each separate IDAT chunk data and then decompress to a single buffer).
- Now you will have a raw but *unfiltered* PNG bitmap

We can still not merge the files as we need to decode each scan-line using the filter byte. There are five different line-filters in PNG where 0 means no filtering is needed, up to the more complex 4 Paeth filter.

In addition, the image can be interlaced (Adam-7) which require a different approach due to being progressive.

When you have decoded each scan-line (and de-interlaced if needed) you will have a raw bitmap unaffected by ICC/gamma from the browser.

An extra step needs to be taken to check if both images are of the same kind (e.g. RGB, RGBA, etc.) If not then one has to in addition, be converted to the other format usually by "upgrading" the one with less information/quality. If the same format and depth you should be good to go.

If the size differs in such a way it would leave some sort of gap in the final result, padding may be needed to fill empty pixels where there is no coverage, depending on format and if don't want things such as transparency etc.

Now you can merge the two bitmaps horizontally or vertically.

### Merging two bitmaps

You mentioned you wanted to merge the bitmaps horizontally -

- Set up a new buffer the size of image 1 width + image 2 width times the size of a single pixel (3 for RGB, 4 for RGBA etc.)
- Define height as the maximum of the two heights
- Determine if you need/want to use padding/zero-fill (height 1 !== height 2)

Set up a main loop for the new buffer, then alternate between image 1 and 2 per scan-line so that the two first scan-lines are copied as a single one into the new buffer.

### Writing process

The reverse process to save out the image again is then:

- Set signature
- Add IHDR chunk and update with new sizes, format, depth
- Add IDAT chunk

  - Encode each scanline (you can use filter 0 for simplicity, but it will add to size)
  - Deflate the data using zlib and add. Update size of the chunk using the compressed size
  - [Calculate CRC-32 checksums](http://www.simplycalc.com/crc32-source.php)
- Add IEND chunk

My strategy would be to build the file in parts using a plain Array to hold each typed array part (signature) and chunk + data. Then pass the array to a Blob which will concatenate the parts to a single binary buffer.

For example:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(taSig);   // ta* = typed array
arr.push(taIHDR);
arr.push(taIDAT);
arr.push(taIEND);
```

Then pass in the array to a Blob:

```
var blob = new Blob(arr, {type: "image/png"});
```

---

The complete PNG file format specification can be found **[here](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html)**.

I will recommend you to check out my **[pngtoy](https://github.com/epistemex/pngtoy)** (PNG parser and decoder, MIT lic.) for details. It do similar steps as described above to obtain a raw decoded bitmap.

Comment: Fantastic and comprehensive answer. This is really what I was after: the format of a decoded png byte array. I will test this and give you best answer if it works.

Comment: Updated with more details.

Comment: Turns out it's easier to reprocess my db of images to split the file to begin with (to save the client any processing lag time) - that being said, this is the answer to the question I was looking for at the time (and may need in the future!) Cheers.